# Pig Elephant-Bird Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Tags: hadoop, lzo, elephantbird

I am running Hadoop 2.0 with CDH4 and built elephant-bird library with Oracle Java 1.6 r31

My Pig Script:

```
register elephant-bird-2.2.3.jar

log = load 'loggy.log.lzo' using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.store.LzoPigStorage(' ');

limited = limit log 100;

dump limited;
```

Result:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2117: Unexpected error when launching map reduce job.

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias limited
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:696)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:320)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:475)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.PigException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias limited
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:937)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:900)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:813)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2117: Unexpected error when launching map reduce job.
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:352)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1266)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:933)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve error that occured when launching map reduce job: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.LzoInputFormat.listStatus(LzoInputFormat.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:248)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.LzoInputFormat.getSplits(LzoInputFormat.java:111)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:945)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:270)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:160)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:257)

    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$JobControlThreadExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(MapReduceLauncher.java:676)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1874)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.LzoInputFormat.listStatus(LzoInputFormat.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:248)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.LzoInputFormat.getSplits(LzoInputFormat.java:111)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:945)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:270)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:160)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:257)
================================================================================
```

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by an incompatibility between the Hadoop version expected by the elephant-bird library and the one that is installed ([this bug report](https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo/issues/56) describes a similar problem). The latest version of elephant-bird contains [Hadoop API wrappers](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/#hadoop-api-wrappers) that solve the issue.

Try the [latest version of the elephant-bird library](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/twitter/elephantbird/) - you need three jars - and register them in pig:

```
register 'elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar';
register 'elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
register 'elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
```

That solved the problem for me.